# What is the method or class or whatever that show me the configurations files of JRuby?

Tags: jruby, configuration-files

I'm new to JRuby, I installed it on windows 8, and I'm following it's wiki. When the wiki said to change a configuration option, it dose not say exactally where I can find the file where the option resides, it gives only its name but not the full path.
So is their  a method that I can run on jirb to find the path to any configuration path.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `.jrubyrc` file is searched in your current directory (`user.dir` Java property), your home directory (`user.home`), and since you're on Windows, also in `HOMEDRIVE\HOMEPATH`, in this order (and the first one wins).